# Dummy variables and the weekend effect

Tags: regression, categorical-data, categorical-encoding, finance

I am running a regression to see the well documented "weekend effect" in the stock market. The weekend effect is a phenomenon in financial markets in which stock returns on Mondays are often significantly lower than those of the immediately preceding Friday

The regression equation for which is as follows: [image: formula]

Where R is the return on the day t, D1,D2...,D5 are binary dummy variables for the days of the week Monday, Tuesday Wednesday etc and e is the error term.

I want to add specific "special" Mondays, for example, the first Monday in March and see if it is different to a regular Monday return.

Is this as simple as adding another binary dummy variable? For example

[image: formula]

Where the new term is a binary dummy variable that equals 1 on the first Monday of March and the original Monday dummy variable has been edited to now be 1 on all Mondays except the first Monday of March where it is now 0?

If so when I run a regression in excel can I simply select the return data as my Y-axis and both "regular Monday" and "special Monday" dummy variables as my X-axis? Or have I fallen into some dastardly statistical trap?